# how to use one line to calculate maximum of values every a number of lines

Tags: awk

**updated 4**

finally succeed by replace comma with nothing first

```
sed -i -e 's/,//g' ./test.txt
```

**updated 3**

```
gawk -v FPAT="\"$re\"|'$re'|([^,]*)" 'max2<${2/,/}{max2=${2/,/}} max3<$3{max3=$3} !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}' ./test.txt
```

i try to replace comma inside variable of the body when defined limiter not work
but error

```
gawk: max2<${2/,/}{max2=${2/,/}} max3<$3{max3=$3} !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}
gawk:       ^ syntax error
gawk: max2<${2/,/}{max2=${2/,/}} max3<$3{max3=$3} !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}
gawk:          ^ syntax error
gawk: max2<${2/,/}{max2=${2/,/}} max3<$3{max3=$3} !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}
gawk:                         ^ unterminated regexp
gawk: cmd. line:1: max2<${2/,/}{max2=${2/,/}} max3<$3{max3=$3} !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}
gawk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

**updated2**

```
 re='[[:space:]]|,[[:space"]]'
gawk -v FPAT="\"$re\"|'$re'" '{print $2}' ./test.txt
```

i used this command, but when print second column,

it ended with a number and comma,  "5615338,"    but not number only 5615338

**updated:**
Example input

```
2017/07/01_00:05 10619159, 4056079
2017/07/01_00:10 21226878, 4701043
2017/07/01_00:15 21226878, 5950847
2017/07/01_00:20 16363494, 5950847
2017/07/01_00:25 14633717, 3741938
2017/07/01_00:30 15704459, 4635459
2017/07/01_00:35 21998339, 5317282
2017/07/01_00:40 21998339, 5317282
2017/07/01_00:45 16374904, 4908459
2017/07/01_00:50 14202981, 4908459
2017/07/01_00:55 14079446, 5883581
2017/07/01_01:00 13103851, 5883581
2017/07/01_01:05 15507895, 2809263
2017/07/01_01:10 18997682, 2528104
2017/07/01_01:15 18997682, 2422419
2017/07/01_01:20 11074793, 2738467
2017/07/01_01:25 7052341, 3305620
2017/07/01_01:30 8575741, 3305620
2017/07/01_01:35 8575741, 2954594
2017/07/01_01:40 8428957, 2954594
2017/07/01_01:45 6572863, 2567163
2017/07/01_01:50 9342291, 2073510
2017/07/01_01:55 10468132, 2073510
2017/07/01_02:00 10872895, 1918255
2017/07/01_02:05 13468878, 1983474
2017/07/01_02:10 13468878, 1983474
2017/07/01_02:15 8947705, 1788545
2017/07/01_02:20 2908146, 1608482
2017/07/01_02:25 2553990, 2154687
2017/07/01_02:30 2529649, 2229552
2017/07/01_02:35 4735841, 2679731
2017/07/01_02:40 4735841, 2679731
2017/07/01_02:45 2686580, 1795024
2017/07/01_02:50 1204155, 1795024
2017/07/01_02:55 1473997, 1577228
2017/07/01_03:00 1571244, 1852244
2017/07/01_03:05 1571244, 1852244
2017/07/01_03:10 1486433, 1574531
2017/07/01_03:15 1404316, 1574531
2017/07/01_03:20 1238772, 1138933
2017/07/01_03:25 1186353, 1138933
2017/07/01_03:30 1082074, 1459387
2017/07/01_03:35 1082074, 1459387
2017/07/01_03:40 1192972, 1414292
2017/07/01_03:45 1340513, 1388572
2017/07/01_03:50 1490070, 1388572
2017/07/01_03:55 1490070, 1319763
2017/07/01_04:00 974498, 1100755
2017/07/01_04:05 1048620, 1089887
2017/07/01_04:10 1048620, 1089887
2017/07/01_04:15 653530, 981357
2017/07/01_04:20 665320, 1156669
2017/07/01_04:25 665320, 1156669
2017/07/01_04:30 791647, 1108627
2017/07/01_04:35 791647, 1204707
2017/07/01_04:40 1585158, 1204707
2017/07/01_04:45 1585158, 1234179
2017/07/01_04:50 664379, 1234179
2017/07/01_04:55 669504, 1134438
2017/07/01_05:00 1392480, 1223190
2017/07/01_05:05 1392480, 1223190
2017/07/01_05:10 810646, 1104696
2017/07/01_05:15 787808, 1008312
2017/07/01_05:20 809652, 1247696
2017/07/01_05:25 809652, 1277104
2017/07/01_05:30 776918, 1277104
2017/07/01_05:35 1216307, 1058635
2017/07/01_05:40 1216307, 1226774
2017/07/01_05:45 1628582, 1226774
2017/07/01_05:50 2695521, 1156884
2017/07/01_05:55 2695521, 1344584
2017/07/01_06:00 2732553, 1344584
2017/07/01_06:05 2794176, 2654515
2017/07/01_06:10 2794176, 2654515
2017/07/01_06:15 2580823, 2578247
2017/07/01_06:20 3342221, 2373548
2017/07/01_06:25 6095447, 2501782
2017/07/01_06:30 6095447, 3032341
2017/07/01_06:35 2642484, 3280565
2017/07/01_06:40 3445436, 3310250
2017/07/01_06:45 5505926, 3310250
2017/07/01_06:50 5505926, 2981384
2017/07/01_06:55 6179556, 2498714
2017/07/01_07:00 6179556, 2498714
2017/07/01_07:05 5862156, 2599012
2017/07/01_07:10 5792697, 2599012
2017/07/01_07:15 7817501, 3143155
2017/07/01_07:20 7817501, 3143155
2017/07/01_07:25 6658178, 3056959
2017/07/01_07:30 6658178, 2944126
2017/07/01_07:35 5871045, 3088451
2017/07/01_07:40 5871045, 3266807
2017/07/01_07:45 5607171, 3332246
2017/07/01_07:50 4876884, 3772675
2017/07/01_07:55 6247666, 3772675
2017/07/01_08:00 6247666, 3671781
2017/07/01_08:05 5615338, 3558779
```

**Expected output**

```
2017/07/01_04:00    21998339    5950847
2017/07/01_08:00    7817501 3772675
```

how to use one line to calculate maximum of values every a number of lines

for change every 5 minutes MRTG data into every 4 hours data using maximum value every 48 rows for calculate price

i write below, but the max value are incorrect, i suspect that the awk see the value as string, then i add +1-1 to cast it into number, but still is wrong, where is wrong?

```
 awk 'NR==1 {sum2max=$2+1-1;sum3max=$3+1-1;} (NR>1 && sum2max<$2) {sum2max=$2+1-1;} NR>1 && sum3max<$3 {sum3max=$3+1-1;} (NR%48)==0 {print NR,$1,sum2max,sum3max;sum2max=0; sum3max=0;}'
```

Comment: You also have to show what your input data looks like, otherwise it's impossible to understand what you're trying to do. Ideally, you'd also show what your desired output looks like.

Comment: Your code works fine for me --- can you show some input where you're not getting the expected result?  Also `$2+0` is sufficient to convert strings to numbers, but it's not needed in this case. Input fields that look like numbers will be compared numerically with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify the code little bit

```
$ awk 'max2<$2{max2=$2} 
       max3<$3{max3=$3} 
      !(NR%48){print NR,$1,max2,max3; max2=max3=0}' file
```

since you're OK with resetting the max to zero, you can remove the initialization `NR==1`, also `+1-1` seems redundant, `awk` should be able to cast numbers correctly, if not `+0` should suffice.

Comment: when i apply same command in another Red hat machine, it show incorrect maximum, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxs_ao6uuBDUTWRoZ2liR01RcnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your number has a comma which might be the reason.  Better to post a subset of your data to the question so that people can test the scripts.

Comment: really caused by comma, but how to use multiple delimiter , comma and space ?